# Ember.js - What is the best way to store application specific data in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to access the application specific data in my components as well as routes. I also need to set the application specific data from normal JS.

I have currently created an object with global namespaces (App.globalSetting) and then created the variables as properties on this object.

I am then able to set and get the variable using App.globalSetting.set() and App.globalSetting.get().

Is the above method a good practice or is there a better way to do the same.

Also the data to be stored is critical. So please suggest a best way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Services: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/services/.

From the guides:

"An Ember.Service is a long-lived Ember object that can be injected as needed."

Example service:

**settings-service.js**

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  exampleSetting: true,
  update(value) {
    this.set('exampleSetting', value);
  }
});
```

How to access this service from a Component (or Route):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  settings: Ember.inject.service('settings-service'),
  actions: {
    doSomething(val) {
      this.get('settings').update(val);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :-). Could you please let me know if this is safe to have details such as user access for particular functionality in the application??.  And also how will I be able to set the properties of the service from other javascript function that are not in Ember (Simple javascript). Is it possible or not???

Comment: I'm not an expert on security, but I don't think it's a good idea to store credentials on the client side. And since the Service is an Ember object, I don't think it's possible to use it outside of Ember.